# Oracle SQL Developer - How to save the whole result

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv

When I ran a query, it only displayed 50 rows. But when I click export, would I get the whole result? If not, how can I export the whole result into a csv file? Thanks.

Comment: First of all, try to export the data yourself and see if it is exporting all the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a query, we do a single fetch of the results to populate the grid.

As you scroll, we get more rows, in batches of 50.

This setting can be increased to 250 rows per fetch (Database, Advanced, Array Size).

When you do an export, we grab the ENTIRE result set.